# How to add an hour in timestamp in sql server (without Declare)

Tags: sql-server, dateadd

I want to add an hour in the parameter TimeStamp, but not with declare parameter i.e

```
DECLARE @datetime2 datetime2 = '2019-03-01T09:25:21.1+01:00'
                SELECT DATEADD(hour,1,@datetime)
```

I have a  column name TimeStamp in a table and i want to add in all data plus 1 hour.

The column

```
TimeStamp 
2019-03-01T09:25:20.1+01:00
2019-03-01T09:25:21.1+01:00
2019-03-01T09:25:19.1+01:00
```

I try something like this

```
SELECT DATEADD(hour,1, TimeStamp), but i have an error
```

> Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character
>   string.

Any possible answers ??
Thanks

Comment: how T came in Timestamp

Comment: Are you storing datetimes in a varchar column ? Really ? I mean really ?  If that is the case that you made this mistake, than at least store them in a format that is not depending on regional settings, see this http://karaszi.com/the-ultimate-guide-to-the-datetime-datatypes The best thing to do however is to alter this table and store the values in the correct format, DateTime2 or DateTime

Comment: I couldn't change it to datetime because I call timestamp  through web api , which has the format  like this 2019-03-01T09:25:19.1+01:00.I  try to store it as datetime  before post this question but i had the same problem

Comment: that mean this is fixed format for your timestamp, do some formatting before storing in your column or take the date part out from this string and apply your condition.

Comment: Good news! Although there are many answers the number thereof is still within the sample space of a die throw... :)

Comment: @chrysa22, was your question addressed?. If so,  can you please mark it as answered?

Answer (score 4):

SELECT DATEADD(hour,1, TimeStamp) is correct

However, The format in TimeStamp is wrong,

So,  cast it to DateTime2 First

```
CAST(TimeStamp as DateTime2)
```

OR

```
CAST('2019-03-01T09:25:20.1+01:00' as DateTime2)
```

So,

```
SELECT DATEADD(hour, 1, CAST(TimeStamp as DateTime2))
```

Answer (score 1):

> Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character
>   string.

The error message means that column TimeStamp stored as a string. DATEADD expects a valid value that is date/datetime/datetime2 or can be converted into it from a string.  Because a sample value look like `DATETIME2`, such extra conversion perhaps is needed:

```
SELECT DATEADD(hour,1, CAST(TimeStamp as datetime2))
```

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax will be fine as defined.

It might be a value in your column that is not able to parse to datetime2 because it contains an invalid character.
You could add the ISDATE() to the expression to check if it is valid.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/isdate-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

edit: forgot to mention you could parse before adding with try_cast or try_convert to datetime2

Answer (score 0):

In Your Timestamp **+01:00** represents the Time offset to GMT. You can convert this to your local time and then Add the Hours using DATEADD()

or Remove the Time Offset from the string and add one hour using DATEADD() As suggested by Others.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are after this?

```
 select dateadd(hour,1,convert(datetimeoffset, TimeStamp))
```

Best to not store dates and times as text though.

Edit: Note that his will retain your time zone information if that is important to you.

Answer (score 0):

According to this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017#date-and-time-styles
you have to convert the timestamp with timezone using type 127.

127 is the input format for:

> ISO8601 with time zone Z.
>
> yyyy-mm-ddThh:mi:ss.mmmZ (no spaces)
> Note: For a milliseconds (mmm) value of 0, the millisecond decimal value will not  display. For example, the value '2012-11-07T18:26:20.000 will display as '2012-11-07T18:26:20'.

```
select convert(datetime2, '2019-03-01T09:25:20.1+01:00', 127)
```

if you are not using `convert` and the 127 by using `cast` you may run in conversion problems depending on language settings of the users.